# Wrap all images with a div using DOMDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I have a large html document, with several images. I want to wrap all the images inside `div.wrapped`. How would I do this with `DOMDocument`?

I've seen the `appendChild` method, but that only appends elements at the end. How can I insert one in the middle, and then move the image inside it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I never used DOMdocument before, but I think you mean something like this:

```
$html = <<<EOF
<html>
    <head>
        <title>:( -> :)</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="www.com" />
        <div class="random">
            <img src="www.ru" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
EOF;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

//Create new wrapper div
$new_div = $dom->createElement('div');
$new_div->setAttribute('class','wrapper');

//Find all images
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

//Iterate though images
foreach ($images AS $image) {
    //Clone our created div
    $new_div_clone = $new_div->cloneNode();
    //Replace image with this wrapper div
    $image->parentNode->replaceChild($new_div_clone,$image);
    //Append this image to wrapper div
    $new_div_clone->appendChild($image);
}
```

Comment: amazing bro! you rock!