# PHP XPath how to wrap contents of p's in a span

Tags: php, html, xml, xpath

I don't know if you can read JS Jquery but this is what I'd like to do server sided instead of client sided: `$('p').wrapInner('<span class="contentsInP" />');` I'd like to take all existing paragraphs from a page and wrap their contents in a new span with a specific class.

Luckily all my documents are HTML5 in its XML flavour and are valid so that in PHP I can do this (simplified):

```
$xml=new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);  
// How to go on in here to wrap my p's?
$output=$xml->saveXML();
```

How do I get PHP's DOMXPath to do my wrapping?

**EDIT:** Fiddled with this based on the comment but couldn't make it work

```
// based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426391/wrap-all-images-with-a-div-using-domdocument    
$xml=new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML(utf8_encode($temp));
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);  
//Create new wrapper div
$new_span = $xml->createElement('span');
$new_span->setAttribute('class','contentsInP');
$ps = $xml->getElementsByTagName('p');
//Find all p
//Iterate though p
foreach ($ps AS $p) {
  //Clone our created span
  $new_span_clone = $new_span->cloneNode();
  //Replace p with this wrapper span
  $p->parentNode->replaceChild($new_span_clone,$p);
  //Append the p's contents to wrapper span
  // THIS IS THE PROBLEM RIGHT NOW:
  $new_span_clone->appendChild($p);
}
$temp=$xml->saveXML();
```

The above wraps the p in a span but I need a span wrapping the p's contents while keeping the p around the span... Furthermore the above fails if the p has a class, then it won't be touched.

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426391/wrap-all-images-with-a-div-using-domdocument

Comment: @har07 fiddled with that example for an hour now but couldn't make it work for the p's contents - I did add the code as far as I got to the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In attempting to adapt that other answer, the primary thing that needs to change with it is to get all child nodes of the `<p>` element, first *remove them* as children from `<p>` then *append them* as children onto the `<span>`.  Then finally, append the `<span>` as a child node of the `<p>`.

```
$html = <<<HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>xyz</title></head>
<body>
<div>
<p><a>inner 1</a></p>
<p><a>inner 2</a><div>stuff</div><div>more stuff</div></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
HTML;

$xml=new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML(utf8_encode($html));

//Create new wrapper div
$new_span = $xml->createElement('span');
$new_span->setAttribute('class','contentsInP');
$ps = $xml->getElementsByTagName('p');
//Find all p
//Iterate though p
foreach ($ps AS $p) {
  //Clone our created span
  $new_span_clone = $new_span->cloneNode();

  // Get an array of child nodes from the <p>
  // (because the foreach won't work properly over a live nodelist)
  $children = array();
  foreach ($p->childNodes as $child) {
    $children[] = $child;
  }

  // Loop over that list of child nodes..
  foreach ($children as $child) {
    // Remove the child from the <p>
    $p->removeChild($child);
    // Append it to the span
    $new_span_clone->appendChild($child);
  }
  // Lastly, append the <span> as a child to the <p>
  $p->appendChild($new_span_clone);
}
$temp=$xml->saveXML();
```

Given the input HTML fragment, this should produce output like: ([demonstration...](http://codepad.viper-7.com/XHoEJJ))

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>xyz</title></head>
<body>
<div>
<p><span class="contentsInP"><a>inner 1</a></span></p>
<p><span class="contentsInP"><a>inner 2</a><div>stuff</div><div>more stuff</div></span></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When using this the added nodes get a namespace like this in the HTML for me: "<br xmlns:default="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"/>" Do you know why that is?

Comment: @C.O. Probably due to using `saveXML()` instead of `saveHTML()`.